# Store 10 seconds of unencoded video buffer using Python

Tags: python, picamera

I am trying to save 10 seconds of buffered video using Python script, in particular '.rgb' format.

In order to do so, I have been using a PiCamera connected to a Raspberry Pi.

Based on the script below, if I choose to save the video using h264 format, I will be able to accomplish the desired goal successfully but if change the format from h264 to .rgb (targeted format), no outputs are generated.

Any thoughts what might be the issue here?

Thanks

Code snap:

```
import time
import io
import os 
import picamera
import datetime as dt
from PIL import Image
import cv2 

#obtain current time
def return_currentTime():
    return dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#trigger event declaration
def motion_detected():
    while True:
        print ("Trigger event(y)?")
        trigger = input ()
        if trigger =="y":
            time = return_currentTime()
            print ("Buffering...")
            camera.wait_recording(5)     
            stream.copy_to(str(time)+'.rgb')            
           
        else: 
           camera.stop_recording()
           
           break
        
#countdown timer 
def countdown (t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod (t,60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t-=1
    print('Buffer available!')
   

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

camera.resolution = (640, 480)

stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds = 5)

#code will work using h264 as format
camera.start_recording (stream, format = 'rgb')
countdown(5)
motion_detected()
```

Comment: Please don't link to code.  Instead, post an [mcve] here and format as code (with the `{}` tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has to do with your stream format and how `stream.copy_to()` works.

According to the [docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/api_streams.html#picamera.PiCameraCircularIO.copy_to) for the function `copy_to(output, size=None, seconds=None, first_frame=2)`, first_frame is a restriction on the first frame to be copied. This is set to `sps_header` by default, which is usually the first frame of an H264 stream.

Since your stream format is RGB instead of H264, though, there *are* no sps_header's, and so `copy_to` cannot find an sps_header and copies nothing.

To solve this, you have to allow any frame to be the first frame, not just sps_header's. This can be done by setting `first_frame=None` in your call, like `copy_to(file, first_frame=None)`.

Comment: First problem solved...but now I might be at the edge of facing a new one. After applying the changes, I noticed that generated unencoded files (e.g. rgb, yuv) are smaller than  generated encoded data files(e.g. h264). Shouldn't it be the other way around? Am I missing anything here? 
Thanks,

Comment: @Bert that's strange. Can you run `file output.rgb` to figure out the format of your output, and maybe hexdump the first few tens of bytes here? Let's try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hi @id01, please see the info requested below (first command): 
 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ file 2020-09-02\ 11\:13\:31.rgb 
2020-09-02 11:13:31.rgb: data

Comment: second command:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ hexdump 2020-09-02\ 11\:13\:31.rgb 
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
08ca000

Comment: @Bert it looks like your video is completely black, which is very strange. Does the script work with h264?

Comment: @ id01 Yes, it does. It produces an output for both formats h264 and rgb. The main difference is that for h264, I need to remove the first_frame line in order for the script to work.

Comment: @Bert I mean, does it produce a completely black output with h264? Or does the output actually have images?

Comment: @id01- yes, the output has images. Thank you very much for all the help, I really appreciate it sir. I will put on hold this task for now and proceed with h264 encoder since I need to implement other functionalities.

Comment: That's very strange. I can't really figure out why it's doing that - maybe a bitrate problem?